# How soon is "Just Played"

Tags: arcana

Ainoa and some other general have an ability which reads:

> *Force an opponent to move an Agent he just played to a different District*

Does this mean I have to use the ability **at the same time** as the player is playing the Agent? Or can I wait a another players turn, or right before they place *another* Agent to refer to the "Just played" agent from previously?

For instance, if it is possible to wait, then a tactic that could be used is to wait and see what other players place first, or if the player next turn uses a relic - the ability can be used then on the previous Agent.

The rules are not clear on this.

Answer (score -2):

My understanding of this is that it should be from the current round of play.

I must admit but it's been a while since I've played Arcana. Good game, with enough innovations to have a place among my deck builders!

Comment: Please, explain why you think this is how it works or add a reference to some reliable source. Avoid answering with vague opinions and share your knowledge or research.

Comment: Yes, this is not a ruling/clarification from AEG or FFG. It's an interpretation. Have not been able to find any official rulings.